# Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget-package, plesk

I'm using a url routing tool for friendly urls. I developed an asp.net web form app using this tool. It's great working my local IIS. If I deploy to my web hosting, it's [giving an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIHn5.jpg) about SecurityPermission.

How can I fix this error?

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(String virtualPath, IPrincipal user, String verb) +42
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Abstractions.UrlAuthorizationModuleWrapper.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(String virtualPath, IPrincipal user, String verb) +14
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.GetWebObjectFactory(HttpContextBase httpContext, String modifiedVirtualPath) +159
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.Resolve(HttpContextBase httpContext, IList`1 extensions, String virtualPathOverride, IFriendlyUrlRouteSupportFunctions supportFunctions) +220
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Abstractions.IFriendlyUrlRouteSupportFunctions.Resolve(HttpContextBase httpContext, IList`1 extensions, String virtualPathOverride) +16
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext, String pathOverride, IFriendlyUrlRouteSupportFunctions supportFunctions) +140
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext, String pathOverride) +9
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlsModule.RedirectToFriendlyUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, IFriendlyUrlRoute route, IVirtualPathUtility virtualPathUtility) +346
   Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrlsModule.<Init>b__0(Object sender, EventArgs e) +171
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +141
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: The exception tells you what you need to do, have you tried that?

Comment: NO, i haven't I can't able to understand what is exception tell. I think I have to change in web.config file?

Comment: A web.config edit might not work with your hosting provider, it depends. You might have to get in touch with them to adjust your trust level settings

Comment: Thank, Security issue is fixed This is due to third party DLL, I am changed in web.config by this    <trust level=" Full" />